# Replace string with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text inside a javascript string variable:

> here is some text Page.Title = "info with åäö"; here is more text

I need to target the following and get it placed in a javascript variable (including the quotes):

> Page.Title = "info with åäö";

so I can manipulate that into this:

> Page.Title = " some other info with 123";

and replace and put back into the string so it looks like this:

> here is som text Page.Title = "some other info like 123"; here is more
>   text

The "Page.Title =" are always the same as well as the last semicolon, but the string between the quotes, like:
"info with åäö";
can vary

So how can I best target that and change that string with another string?

This is what I tried:

```
strFind = /Page.Title = [a-z]+/;
strHTML_value = here is some text Page.Title = "info with åäö"; here is more text
strToBeReplace = strHTML_value.match(strFind)[1]
alert(' strToBeReplace ' + strToBeReplace); // = Page.Title = "info with åäö";
strNewValue = Page.Title = "some other info like 123";
strHTML_value = strHTML_value.replace(strToBeReplace, strNewValue);
```

Comment: Two lines of your code are not even syntactically correct...

Comment: could there be backslash-escaped quotes and backslash-escaped backslashes inside the quotes? Will the quoted text ever use single quotes instead of double?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following regex/code:

```
var str = 'here is some text Page.Title = "info with åäö"; here is more text';
var replaceWith = 'some other info like 123';
str = str.replace(/(.*Page\.Title = ")([^"]+)(".*)/gi, '$1' + replaceWith + '$3');
```

Note that the `"[^"]+"` sequence finds an opening quote, followed by one or more non-quote characters, followed by a closing quote.

Comment: Ah, too late with my answer, though my code matches a smaller amount of text.

Comment: It must be great having such a knowledge... :-) Thank you very much. It was exactly what I was looking for. You guys are true heroes!

Comment: @lars I won't lie. It is pretty awesome. :-) But it's easily obtained by constantly self-educating on sites like StackOverflow and others. If you constantly seek to get better and learn more, you will!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at some Regular Expression in JavaScript context:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

First of all your code has some syntax errors, but besides that, your regex will not do what you want it to.

```
var titleRegex = /Page\.Title\s=\s(".+")/;
var stringValue = "here is some text Page.Title = \"info with åäö\"; here is more text";
var replaceValue = "A New Title";
var newTitle = stringValue.replace(/(Page\.Title\s=\s")([^"]+)(")/, '$1' + replaceValue + '$3');
```